# When do changes to Sublime Text 3 syntax files take effect?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, syntax-highlighting, sublime-syntax

I'm writing a syntax definition for Sublime Text 3, using the [new YAML fornat](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html) and not the deprecated one.  I'm not seeing changes to the text I'm trying to highlight, though.  **When are changes to my syntax definition file applied to the files it's meant to highlight?**  And if I can force a definition reload, how can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to `.sublime-syntax` files take effect as soon as they are saved - ST detects any changes made when the file is within the `Packages` folder structure. You can see this in the ST console (View menu -> Show Console) when saving the file:

> generating syntax summary

Unfortunately, there is no timestamp on the entries, so sometimes it can help to manually enter something into the console to help visually separate the lines. i.e.

```
import time; time.asctime(time.localtime())
```

> 'Mon Jan  8 09:11:06 2018'

then, you know any lines that appear under that in the console happened after that time.

One caveat is that ST currently doesn't detect changes automatically when the files are in a symlinked folder: https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1154

In such cases, the only way to get ST to reload modified/new files is by restarting ST.